# Linear actuator - Wiring and control

Tags: control, wiring, actuator

I have to use a linear actuator in my project and according to my need and availability I found this [Linear actuator MEGAMAT2](http://www.elimomotors.com/). This requires 24 V supply. 
[image]

But I am unable to understand the pin configuration diagram provided by dealer [image]

I think yellow, green and black are for moving forward and backward at full stroke speed and also red, white, blue are for controlling the speed of stroke. But I am still struggling with this pin diagram. Please help about this issue.

Comment: Product datasheet should explain all these.

Comment: It looks to me as though the yellow/green pair directly drives the motor and the rest is probably connect to an internal quadrature encoder ("Puls" ... ?) to tell you how far the actuator has moved.